# Non-Repeating Random Numbers for Multiple Variables

Tags: python, function, random

I am trying to create a function that applies random values to a range of parameters that are used in another function where the random sequence does not repeat.

The reason: used for random hyper parameter tuning and to cut down on processing by not repeating sequence.

Example Code:

```
num_evals = 2500

parameters = {
        'n_parameter_1': range(2,100),
        'n_parameter_2': range(1,20),
        'n_parameter_3': range(2,150),
              }  

for i in range(num_evals):
        n_parameter_1 = random.choice(parameters['n_parameter_1'])
        n_parameter_2 = random.choice(parameters['n_parameter_2'])
        n_parameter_3 = random.choice(parameters['n_parameter_3'])
```

The results then get populated to a file with the random parameters used to generate.

I need help with the second bit.

As this function runs over time, you start getting sequences that look like this:

n_parameter_1 = 54, n_parameter_2 = 15, n_parameter_3 = 120

n_parameter_1 = 10, n_parameter_2 = 12, n_parameter_3 = 89

**n_parameter_1 = 54, n_parameter_2 = 15, n_parameter_3 = 120**

I want to avoid the last sequence by either capturing the sequences in a list or dataframe etc. (already saving the sequences) that the function checks and then generates a new/different sequence if there is a duplicate sequence in the list.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What's the question? How to avoid repetiition?

Comment: What is your actual problem? You've got the first part down, "create a function that applies random values to a range of parameters", and it's unclear to me what you mean by "where the random sequence does not repeat".

Comment: Sorry, made an edit to make it more clear

Comment: Have you tried `random.shuffle` instead of `random.choice` ?

Comment: `random.shuffle` and `random.sample` provide a set of non-recurring numbers out of the original sample. See the documentation for details and some examples. Thus, first create a list for each random parameters, then iterate over these lists. Don't try and pick a random parameter each time inside a loop; prepare that before the loop.

Comment: Have you considered that random sampling might not be your best approach? With a suitable design of experiments you could perhaps fit a response surface model which could tell you the impact of each parameter, both individually and jointly via interaction terms, to facilitate your 'tuning' efforts. A good design would likely give you better info with less sampling. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_farming and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_surface_methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store sequences in a set and then check if a sequence is already in the set.

```
num_evals = 2500
i = 0

parameters = {
        'n_parameter_1': range(2,100),
        'n_parameter_2': range(1,20),
        'n_parameter_3': range(2,150),
              }  

sequences = set()

while i < num_evals:
        n_parameter_1 = random.choice(parameters['n_parameter_1'])
        n_parameter_2 = random.choice(parameters['n_parameter_2'])
        n_parameter_3 = random.choice(parameters['n_parameter_3'])
        sequence = (n_parameter_1, n_parameter_2, n_parameter_3)
        if sequence not in sequences:
            sequences.add(sequence)
            i += 1
```

The for loop has been changed to a while loop to allow for the conditional increment.

Comment: Thanks this was easy enough to understand, I could adapt this to fit into my processes and upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.sample` to get a non-repeating set of values from a list of all possibilities.   But, for your scenario, generating a list of possibilities could be prohibitive (just your example would product 275576 entries in that list).

`random.sample` is able to work efficiently with ranges, so, if you write a function to convert an index number into the corresponding parameter combination, you could build a list of combination indexes using `random.sample(range(275576),num_evals)` and then convert these indexes to the actual parameter values:

```
def paramRange(params): # index range of all combinations
    count = 1
    for r in params.values():
        count *= len(r)
    return range(count)

def getParams(params,index): # parameter value combination at index
    result = []
    for r in reversed([*params.values()]):
        index,pIndex = divmod(index,len(r))
        result.append(r[pIndex])
    return dict(zip(params,reversed(result)))
```

output:

```
num_evals = 10 #2500

parameters = {
        'n_parameter_1': range(2,100),
        'n_parameter_2': range(1,20),
        'n_parameter_3': range(2,150),
              }

import random

comboIndexes = random.sample(paramRange(parameters),num_evals)
for index in comboIndexes:
    print(getParams(parameters,index))
        
{'n_parameter_1': 31, 'n_parameter_2': 12, 'n_parameter_3': 14}
{'n_parameter_1': 18, 'n_parameter_2': 12, 'n_parameter_3': 15}
{'n_parameter_1': 11, 'n_parameter_2': 15, 'n_parameter_3': 74}
{'n_parameter_1': 21, 'n_parameter_2': 19, 'n_parameter_3': 78}
{'n_parameter_1': 25, 'n_parameter_2': 12, 'n_parameter_3': 94}
{'n_parameter_1': 52, 'n_parameter_2': 6, 'n_parameter_3': 40}
{'n_parameter_1': 57, 'n_parameter_2': 8, 'n_parameter_3': 53}
{'n_parameter_1': 85, 'n_parameter_2': 12, 'n_parameter_3': 133}
{'n_parameter_1': 66, 'n_parameter_2': 1, 'n_parameter_3': 60}
{'n_parameter_1': 19, 'n_parameter_2': 13, 'n_parameter_3': 80}
```

*With this method, you are not limited to ranges for the `parameters` dictionary, you could have lists of specific values with different data types*

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer, this actually helped/inspired me on another problem.